# Custom Menu UserControl WPF

Tags: wpf

I have created a custom Menu User control in WPF Browser application. How can I achieve Navigation from one page to other page using this Custom Menu User control from Main page. The pages would be displayed in other Frame control of the Main page.

Comment: First I tried without Usercontrol. Just writing the menu code in mainpage and a frame below it. I will be navigating the pages in the Frame. But the actual purpose of creating Menu User Control is after the user logs in from login page which is contained in Main page frame, I want to navigate to other page from there and I don't want to show the Menu bar. I mean it should not be the part of the frame of main page. It should be a new page in web browser application. I am not using MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There are different options to achieve this. Can you provide more details on how you're loading your UI? (i.e. Prism regions/modules, Data Templates, etc.)

My general suggestion would be one of two options:

1. Use a [mediator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx) to have the menu control notify the frame control. MVVM Light has an easy to use [Messenger](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx) implementation, which is a great toolkit to explore, in my opinion.
2. Have both controls contained in one "parent" control (or view model if you're using MVVM) which can then communicate to the frame control since it contains both menu and frame controls.

HTH,
Ben